# django - improve performance of __in queryset in M2M filtering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a models that has a M2M relationship to another model.

These are my models:

```
class Catalogue(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100, null=True)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(Type, db_index=True)
    datetime = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True)


class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is views.py:

```
class all_ads(generic.ListView):
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = 'new_list_view_grid-card.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        city_district = self.request.GET.getlist('city_district')
        usage = self.request.GET.get('usage')
        status = self.request.GET.get('status')

        last2week = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=14)

        status = status.split(',')

        if usage:
            usage = usage.split(',')
        else:
            usage = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']

        intersections = list(set(status).intersection(usage))
        type_q = (Q(type__in=intersections) & Q(type__isnull=False))

        result = models.Catalogue.objects.filter(
            Q(datetime__gte=last2week) &
            type_q &
            ((reduce(operator.or_, (Q(city__contains=x) for x in city_district)) & Q(city__isnull=False)) |
             (reduce(operator.or_, (Q(district__contains=x) for x in city_district)) & Q(district__isnull=False)))
        ).distinct().order_by('-datetime').prefetch_related('type')

        return result
```

I want to filter MySQL db with some queries and return result in a listview.

It works good on a small database, but with large database it takes over 10 seconds to return results. If I delete `type_q` query, It takes 2 seconds (reduce 10 second!).

How can I improve performance of `__in` queryset?

Comment: What if you use simply `Q(type__in=intersections)` for `type_q`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It does't have so much effect ... takes 10 seconds

Comment: likely it is not the `type_q` that is the problem, but the `type_q` acts as a "multiplier", such that the `city__contains` and `detrict__contains` now need to enumerate over the same record multiple times.

Comment: You might also want an index on that `datetime` field if you don't have one (you are using an `order_by` on it).

Comment: What if you first make a query like `cids = Catalogue.objects.filter((reducue__...).values('pk')`, and then work with `.filter(Q(datetime__gte=last2week) & type_q & pk__int=cids`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is Indexed

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know problem is type_q ... because when I set ```type_q = (Q(type__in=[1]) & Q(type__isnull=False))``` It runs so fast

Comment: @omidjahadi: no, this actually confirms that it is not, because you work with a LEFT OUTER JOIN, the number of combinations of `Catalogue` and `Type` increase enormously, and thus also the filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `type_q` itself is not really the culprit, but acts as a multiplier, since now we make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and thus the `__contains` runs over all combinations. This is thus more a peculiarity of two filters that work together

We can omit this with:

```
cat_ids = list(Catalogue.objects.filter(
    Q(*[Q(city__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR) |
    Q(*[Q(district__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR)
).values_list('pk', flat=True))

result = models.Catalogue.objects.filter(
    Q(datetime__gte=last2week),
    type_q,
    pk__in=cat_ids
).distinct().order_by('-datetime').prefetch_related('type')
```

Some database (MySQL is known to *not* optimize a subquery very well), can even do that with a subquery with. So here we do not materialize the list, but let Django work with a subquery:

```
cat_ids = Catalogue.objects.filter(
    Q(*[Q(city__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR) |
    Q(*[Q(district__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR)
).values_list('pk', flat=True)

result = models.Catalogue.objects.filter(
    Q(datetime__gte=last2week),
    type_q,
    pk__in=cat_ids
).distinct().order_by('-datetime').prefetch_related('type')
```

Comment: Hey, this answer of yours reminds me I saw this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408921/inline-formatting-no-longer-works-with-syntax-highlighting) on meta yesterday (You are mentioned in it BTW ;)). It appears that the syntax highlighting is not working properly with inline HTML anymore (I can see you have used `<strong>` when I try editing but it does not appear in the rendered post.)

Comment: Thank you! ... Now time is on 6 seconds! ... but still is too long ... I think it's about pagination ... I guess django load all database on each page ... because with larger database, It takes more time

Comment: @omidjahadi: did you work with the `list(...)` part or with a subquery?

Comment: @omidjahadi: I think that pagination is eventually necessary for all databases that grow, since eventually the data will be too large to process it effectively.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: thanks, I was not aware of that. I think the first user I saw using that was [mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat). I found it quite helpful so started to use that as well :).

Comment: @omidjahadi: for MySQL I would advise the first code fragment, not the latter, since MySQL is usually not very efficient with subqueries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There is not so much difference between them in timing ... pagination is necessary ... but I think it's not work! I'm posting a new question about that ... I would be thankful if you read that

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234590/django-listview-pagination-is-too-slow-on-large-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you use the **Django Debug Toolbar**, long list of element used in filter will make your query like **100 times slower**. If it's your case, just turn the sql module off by unchecking the sql box on the toolbar, if you see a difference, that's it.
Otherwise, it is probably an issue of query optimization and previous answer explain it well.