# django __in queryset with very large list is too slow

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this filter in views:

```
cat_ids = list(models.Catalogue.objects.only('city', 'district').filter(
    Q(*[Q(city__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR) |
    Q(*[Q(district__contains=x) for x in city_district], _connector=Q.OR)
).values_list('pk', flat=True))

result = models.Catalogue.objects.filter(pk__in=cat_ids)
```

cat_ids is a very large list (over 10000 data).

django return result in 5 seconds. How can I improve this query? Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233935/6759844 have you tried not using `list` in `cat_ids`

Comment: @bdbd yes ... but still takes long time

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you use the **Django Debug Toolbar**, long list of items used in filter will make your query like **100 times slower**. If that's your case, just disable the sql module by unchecking the sql box on the toolbar, if you see a difference, that's it.
Otherwise it is probably a query optimisation issue and the previous answer explains it well.